# listView items is not match parent n linear layout

Tags: android, listview

I need to create LinearLayout, which has ListView. I did it with this code:

```
this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    final ListView listView = (ListView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_timer_rollout, null);
    addView(listView);
```

My chat timer rollout is:

```
<ListView
xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
a:layout_width="match_parent"
a:layout_height="wrap_content"
a:background="@color/white"
a:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
a:paddingBottom="12dp"
a:paddingTop="12dp">
```

After creating i've tried to add items in list view like this:

```
final ArrayAdapter<TimeInterval> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),
                                                                R.layout.chat_timer_item,
                                                                R.id.timer_label, TimeInterval.INTERVALS);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Chat timer item has code:

```
<TextView
a:id="@+id/timer_label"
xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
a:layout_width="match_parent"
a:layout_height="wrap_content"
a:paddingBottom="11dp"
a:paddingLeft="@dimen/timer_label_margin_right"
a:paddingTop="11dp"
a:textColor="@color/primary_text"
a:textSize="@dimen/timer_text_size"/>
```

After creating this i see my linear layout on screen, but when i click item it has width wrap_content, not match parent? how to fix it? I've tried to set one more linear layout for inflated with params match_parent, but it didnt help. Thank you!

Comment: Change the second parameter in the `inflate()` call to `this`, and remove the `addView()` call.

Comment: @MikeM.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in the `LayoutInflater#inflate()` method is the (optional) parent `View` of the inflated layout. When you pass `null` for the parent, the Inflater doesn't know which type of `LayoutParams` are appropriate, so it uses a default `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, which has `ViewGroup.WRAP_CONTENT` for both dimensions.

Since your posted code is in your `LinearLayout` subclass, you can pass `this` as the second argument in the `inflate()` call. Also, when you provide the parent `View` in that two-parameter method, the inflated layout is added to it automatically, so you don't need the `addView()` call.

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
    .inflate(R.layout.chat_timer_rollout, this);
```